# Trying to load an image to my future soundboard and it wont work. anyone?

Tags: java, image, processing, image-scaling

So I'm working towards making a soundboard. 
I'm messing around with processing and I would like a image on the screen. however the image wont show when I load it.

```
import ddf.minim.*; import ddf.minim.analysis.*; import ddf.minim.effects.*; import ddf.minim.signals.*;import ddf.minim.spi.*;import ddf.minim.ugens.*;PImage soundboard;PImage [] array= new PImage[0];Minim minim; AudioPlayer player;Boolean player1= false;void setup(){  minim = newMinim(this)  player = minim.loadFile("deadmau5.mp3")  imageMode(CENTER); soundboard=loadImage("https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/544877364916654080/sxoWk6Sz.png");}void draw(){    imageMode(CENTER); soundboard =loadImage("https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/544877364916654080/sxoWk6Sz.png"); } void mousePressed(){  player1=!player1;if (player1){  player.play();}else {  player.pause();  player.rewind();}}
```

for future reference how to i sort out the code with the sampler on this?
I'm such a noob, Yes i know lol. 
Can someone explain why it's not showing? 
thank you very much guys.

Comment: In the future, please provide a [mcve]. Your question has nothing to do with minim, so your example should not contain any minim code. Instead, narrow your problem down to as few lines as possible while still containing enough code so we can copy it and run it ourselves. Also, try to properly format your code so we can read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're never displaying your image. You're loading it, but you aren't displaying it. You need to call the [`image()`](https://www.processing.org/reference/image_.html) function to draw your image to the screen.

```
PImage soundboard;

void setup() {  
  imageMode(CENTER);
  soundboard=loadImage("https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/544877364916654080/sxoWk6Sz.png");
}

void draw() {    
  image(soundboard, 25, 25);
}
```